# Can't create SQLite database in my android app

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, oncreate

I'm using my application object(Android building bloc) to call the database constructor inside my oncreate method.
But i can't figure out why it can't be created.
This is how my code looks like:

my database class, with DbHelper as an inner class:

```
package com.example.pharmacie;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class PhData {
    private static final String TAG = PhData.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE = "ph_info.db";
    private static final String TABLE = "ph_info";

    public static final String C_ID = "_id";
    public static final String C_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    public static final String C_NAME = "Pharmacie ";
    public static final String C_TELE = " ";
    public static final String C_ADRESS = "Tet";
    public static final String C_HAS_SHIFT = "yes"; // yes if night shift
    public static final String C_SCHEDULE = "YYYY-MM-DD";

    private static final String GET_ALL_ORDER_BY = C_CREATED_AT + " DESC";
    private static final String[] MAX_CREATED_AT_COLUMNS = { "max("
            + PhData.C_CREATED_AT + ")" };    
    Context context;
    private DbHelper dbHelper;

    // Inner class: DbHelper implementations 
    class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper() {
            super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSION);
            Log.d(TAG, "Constructor called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating database: " + DATABASE);

            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE + " (" + C_ID
                    + " int primary key, " + C_CREATED_AT + " int, " + C_NAME
                    + " text, " + C_ADRESS + " text, "
                    + C_HAS_SHIFT + " text, " + C_SCHEDULE
                    + " text, " + C_TELE + " text)");

            Log.d(TAG, "database created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("drop table " + TABLE);
            this.onCreate(db);
        }
    } // end of dbhelper class


    public PhData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbHelper = new DbHelper();
        Log.d(TAG, "Initialized data");
    }

    public void close() {
        this.dbHelper.close();
    }

    public void insertOrIgnore(ContentValues values) {
        Log.d(TAG, "insertOrIgnore on " + values);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE, null, values,
                    SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes ALL the data
     */
    public void delete() {
        // Open Database
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // Delete the data
        db.delete(TABLE, null, null);

        // Close Database
        db.close();
    }
}
```

**And here is my application class where i call the constructor to create my db:**

```
package com.example.pharmacie;

import android.app.Application; import android.util.Log;

public class PharmacieApplication extends Application {
          private static final String TAG = PharmacieApplication.class.getSimpleName();       PhData phData;

    @Override   public void onCreate() {        super.onCreate();
        phData = new PhData(this);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreated");    }

    @Override   public void onTerminate() {         super.onTerminate();
        Log.d(TAG, "onTerminated");     }

}
```

And this is what i get in my logcat:

```
04-20 03:15:05.968: D/PhData(368): Constructor called
04-20 03:15:05.968: D/PhData(368): Initialized data
04-20 03:15:05.968: D/PharmacieApplication(368): onCreated
04-20 03:15:06.568: D/JoursListActivity(368): onCreated
```

Comment: You checked in the system file if the DB has not been created in a previous test already?

Answer (score 4):

The database won't actually be created until you ask to access it.  From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html):

> Create a helper object to create, open, and/or manage a database. This
>   method always returns very quickly. The database is not actually
>   created or opened until one of getWritableDatabase() or
>   getReadableDatabase() is called.

Comment: I have my helper object its an inner class of PhData class, or you mean that i have to insert something in my db to trigger the oncreate method?

Comment: @SFN That's right! Specifically you have to call either `getReadableDatabase()` or `getWritableDatabase()`.  You don't actually have to do anything with it I don't believe.

Answer (score 0):

I am changing your code put this code and try.

```
public class PhData {
    private static final String TAG = PhData.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final int VERSION = 1;
    private static final String DATABASE = "ph_info.db";
    private static final String TABLE = "ph_info";

    public static final String C_ID = "_id";
    public static final String C_CREATED_AT = "created_at";
    public static final String C_NAME = "Pharmacie ";
    public static final String C_TELE = " ";
    public static final String C_ADRESS = "Tet";
    public static final String C_HAS_SHIFT = "yes"; // yes if night shift
    public static final String C_SCHEDULE = "YYYY-MM-DD";

    private static final String GET_ALL_ORDER_BY = C_CREATED_AT + " DESC";
    private static final String[] MAX_CREATED_AT_COLUMNS = { "max("
            + PhData.C_CREATED_AT + ")" };    
    Context context;
    private DbHelper dbHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase db;

    // Inner class: DbHelper implementations 
    class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DbHelper() {
            super(context, DATABASE, null, VERSION);
            Log.d(TAG, "Constructor called");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Creating database: " + DATABASE);

            db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE + " (" + C_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                    C_CREATED_AT + " TEXT, " + 
                    C_NAME + " text, " +
                    C_ADRESS + " text, " + 
                    C_HAS_SHIFT + " text, " +
                    C_SCHEDULE + " text, " + 
                    C_TELE + " text)");

            Log.d(TAG, "database created");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            db.execSQL("drop table " + TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }
    } // end of dbhelper class


    public PhData(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbHelper = new DbHelper(context);
        db=this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db=this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.d(TAG, "Initialized data");
    }

    public void close() {
        if (db != null)
            db.close();
    }

    public Database open() throws SQLException{
        this.dbHelper= new ContactsDBHelper(con);
        db=this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        db=this.dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }   

    public void insertOrIgnore(ContentValues values) {
        Log.d(TAG, "insertOrIgnore on " + values);
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        try {
            db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE, null, values,
                    SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
        } finally {
            db.close();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Deletes ALL the data
     */
    public void delete() {
        // Open Database
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

        // Delete the data
        db.delete(TABLE, null, null);

        // Close Database
        db.close();
    }
}
```

May be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Actually i've found out the source problem who led me to another problem:
I have to pass the context of the dbHelper into the constructor to call it from my Application class.

The other erro generated is this:

```
public static final String C_SCHEDULE = "YYYY-MM-DD";
```

you can't use minus sign as separator in the db creation, because the virtual machine consider it as a mathematical sign. so my declaration had to be changed to:

```
public static final String C_SCHEDULE = "YYYY_MM_DD";
```